# jQuery: Simple plugin does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create a plugin with jQuery.
This is the very basic plugin (**plugin.js**)

```
(function ( $ ) { 
$.fn.testPlugin= function() {

  alert('test');

}( jQuery ));
```

This is the file (**ext.js**) which calls the function testPlugin() inside **plugin.js**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('p').testPlugin();

};
```

In the HTML page I included the files above plus the jQuery library (**jquery.js**)

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/plugin.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/ext.js"></script>
```

Unfortunately the plugin does not work as expected.

Comment: Do you actually have a paragraph element in the HTML somewhere?

Comment: Yes, I have p elements in the HTML.

Comment: @AlienBishop even if there are no `<p>` elements, the plugin will be called because jQuery will still construct an (empty) object.

Comment: @AlienBishop no need to have the element in the HTML.

Comment: **Keep your developer console open!**  It gives you answers to why your code doesn't work in milliseconds, making it even faster than Stackoverflow!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, this simple example will work (after I removed the `)` as mentioned by Tibzon and Wojtek).

```js
$.fn.testPlugin=function(){ alert('test'); };

$('p').testPlugin()
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

I left out your enclosing parenthetical expression `(function($){ ... })(jQuery)` as this doesn't really make any difference for the example chosen. The only variable affected is `$` itself.

Answer (score 7):

```
alert('test');  });
```

Isn't this ")" at the end of the line too much?

When I try to test it, it returns a syntax error.

Move it to your ext.js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('p').testPlugin();

});
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a syntax error in your code. That is why its not working. There is an extra `)` in the line below `alert('test');`

Your plugin syntax should be,

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.testPlugin = function () {

        alert('test');
    };

}(jQuery));
```

Working [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunatebel/p7oo4qrd/1/)

Comment: Hi, Tibzon...I corrected the plugin syntax, but I have the same problem. The plugin does not work.

Comment: I have inserted a fiddle to demonstrate. It is working as expected there. May be you should recheck where you have imported the `js` files. Are there in correct places?

Answer (score 0):

Some minor mistake in the code. Corrected them and its working fine:

First part, the parenthesis were misplaced. Here is the correct first section:

```
(function ( $ ) { 
    $.fn.testPlugin= function() {
    alert('test');
}})( jQuery );
```

Second part:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('p').testPlugin();
});
```

Simple and easy :)